# Examples of quadratic extensions K, L of $\mathbb{Q}$ such that KL has some properties.

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, prime-factorization

Let $p$ be a prime integer, I want to find $p$ and K, L  extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ such that

1. K, L contain each a unique prime lying over $p$ but KL does not.

Another, different, triplet such that

2. The residue field extension of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is trivial for K and L but not for KL.

Is there a way to easily compute such examples?

I can give examples of other cases (e.g p totally ramified in K and L but not in KL or inert in K and L but not in KL) but I'm finding the two above a bit more difficoult.

Comment: I'm confused: isn't this impossible by the fundamental identity? I think you want (a) $p$ totally ramified in $K$ and $L$, so ramification index $2$. But then you want (b) at least 2 primes $\mathfrak{P}_1, \mathfrak{P}_2$ above $p$ in $KL$ with residue degrees at least $2$. But $e_i := e_{KL/\mathbb{Q}}(\mathfrak{P_i}) \geq 2$ by multiplicativity of ramification index, so this gives $e_1 f_1 + e_2 f_2 \geq 2 \cdot 2 + 2 \cdot 2 > 4 = [KL : \mathbb{Q}]$.

Comment: For (1), let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ and $L = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$. They each contain a unique prime above $p = 5$. Their compositum is $\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt{5})$ and this contains $2$ primes above $5$ since $5 = (1+2i)(1-2i)$ splits in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

Comment: For the edited question, [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/71380/ramifications-in-compositum-number-fields) has some examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Answering the edited version with the misunderstanding cleared. The answer to the misunderstood version has been deleted, but can be seen in the edit history.)

Observe that because $K/\Bbb{Q}$ and $L/\Bbb{Q}$ are Galois, cyclic of order two, the extension $KL/\Bbb{Q}$ is also Galois with Galois group $C_2\times C_2$. Therefore:

- for each prime $p$, the equation $efg=4$ holds, and
- it is impossible to have $f=4$ for any prime $p$, because then the Galois group should have a subquotient isomorphic to $C_4$.
- Consequently $KL$ will have a third intermediate quadratic field $F$ that we can use as a tool for studying the primes of the compositum.

The second point is a bit more advanced, and not needed to answer this. But it does play a role.

1. Namely, if $f(K/\Bbb{Q},p)=2=f(L/\Bbb{Q},p)$ then the condition (1) is automatic. So we can simply pick two integers $m,n$, coprime to $p$, such that neither is a quadratic residue modulo $p$. Then $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt n)$ and
   $L=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt m)$ will work. For example with $p=5$, $n=2$, $m=7$ we see that 
   $p$ is inert in $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ and in $L=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt7)$. As a product of two quadratic non-residues $2\cdot7=14$ is a quadratic residue modulo $5$, and therefore $5$ splits in $F=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{14})\subset KL$. Consequently, $p=5$ is a product of two prime ideals of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt7)$, both with inertia degree $f=2$.
2. To find an example of (2) we need to use ramification. The prime $p=3$ is ramified in both $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt3)$ and $L=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{15})$, so $f(K/\Bbb{Q},3)=f(L/\Bbb{Q},3)=1$. But $\sqrt{3}\cdot\sqrt{15}=3\sqrt{5}$, so we see that $F=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt5)\subseteq KL$. As $5$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $3$, it follows that $3$ is inert in $F$. Therefore $f(KL/\Bbb{Q},3)=2$ as well.

It may be worth noting that we cannot get (2) when $p$ splits in both $K$ and $L$. For in that case $p$ will split compeletely in $KL$ (the product of two quadratic residues is a quadratic residue). The combination of ramified in $K$ + split in $L$ obviously won't work either. Ramified in both $K$ and $L$ is the only combo that works here. Of course, we still need to be careful for the prime $p$ might still split in the third quadratic intermediate field $F$.

Comment: I think I made the question unclear: the two requirements are separate. I want an example in 1) and an example (that will be different) in 2.

Your answer is indeed useful but still (I have problems with Galois theory) I can't compute the concrete examples

Comment: @Frankie123 The edited question is a bit more interesting! Deleting the old stuff. Hopefully the voters won't mind. It is still viewable in the edit history.